# GradleW causes Mac OS to crash / freeze

Tags: java, android, macos, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I have a big problem with the new Android Studio IDE (migrating projects from Eclipse).

After spending many hours of work migrating all my projects (with libraries) to **Android Studio** I’m not able to build / debug projects with the IDE. Everytime Gradlew finishes the **building process** Mac Os (Yosemite 10.10.1) **freezes / crashes** in a mysterious way. I’m able to click on dock icons or status menu entries but nothing happens. **No program (even terminal) won’t start anymore** (things like spotlight keep working), so I have to turn off my Mac using the power button.

Mac’s activity log doesn’t show helpful information.

I have no clue how to solve this problem. I’ve already tried the following stuff:

- Invalidate cache
- reinstall Android Studio
- reinstall JDK
- reinstall gradle using homebrew
- deleting stuff on my hard drive to increase free storage

**You can find a picture of the terminal output (command: ./gradlew clean build --debug) here: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NKNs.jpg)**

Do you have got any idea how to fix this?

Comment: can you try to build the project by using terminal without IDE? like ./gradlew clean build --debug

Comment: @nr4bt Tried it, but osx freezed again     You can find a picture of the terminaloutput here: [link](http://i.imgur.com/rjxFzMj.png)   I also recognized many 'repaintAllWindows' calls from Finder (in the console)

Comment: It looks to me as if you are pegging your CPU, processing an AAR file, whose name you have blotted out, in your linked image (it ends .libs.holoeverywhere).  If you have a terminal window open, you should be able to avoid restarting the computer by identifying the app that has the CPU pegged (top, ps) and killing it (kill -9).  Try building without the library, first, to see if that finishes.  Then figure out what's wrong with the library (btw, it is possible that there is no problem at all.  It might just take a while...)

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike I tried to use the kill command but even terminal stops responding (after hitting enter nothing happens)    I will try to avoid using the library, but I'm just wondering that the same library files worked with ant (eclipse) ..

Comment: Yeah, I feel your pain.  Gradle is doing something *very* different than eclipse/ant.  It might even be doing the wrong thing.   I am surprised that you can't even get a command line command to work.  That seems odd.

Comment: It's really odd @G.BlakeMeike. Things like Mission Control and MultiWindow (Mac) keep running, but I'm no t able to launch apps. Even "About this Mac" will not work :/